# Number of arrangements of the $10$ letters ABCDEFGHIJ in which none of the patterns ABE, BED, or HID occur

Tags: combinatorics

> Count the number of arrangements of the $10$ letters ABCDEFGHIJ in which none of the patterns ABE, BED, or HID occur.

I thought that the answer would be $_{10}P_{10} - (_{10}P_{3} + _{10}P_{3} + _{10}P_{3} - _{10}P_{2}$), since we have $_{10}P_{10}$ total arrangements, and $_{10}P_{3}$ arrangements for ABE, BED, and HID. But we subtracted $BE$ twice, so we need to add it back in: $_{10}P_{2}$.

Please tell me what is wrong with my reasoning!

Answer (score 2):

There are $10!$ permutations of the ten distinct letters.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which the substrings ABE, BED, or HID appear.

*Arrangements with a prohibited substring*:  We count arrangements in which ABE appears.  We have eight objects to arrange: ABE, C, D, F, G, H, I, J.  Since the objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $8!$ ways.

By symmetry, there are $8!$ arrangements in which BED appears and $8!$ arrangements in which HID appears.

Hence, there are $3 \cdot 8!$ arrangements with a prohibited substring.

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we will have subtracted each arrangement in which two prohibited substrings appear twice, once for each way we could designate one of those substrings as the prohibited one.  We only want to subtract such arrangements once, so we must add them back.

*Arrangements with two prohibited substrings*:  Since it is not possible for a permutation of the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J to contain both BED and HID, this can occur in two ways.  Either both ABE and BED appear in the arrangement or both ABE and HID appear in the arrangement.

Substrings ABE and BED both appear in the arrangement:  This can only occur if the arrangement contains the substring ABED.  Then we have seven objects to arrange: ABED, C, F, G, H, I, J.  Since the objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $7!$ ways.

Substrings ABE and HID both appear in the arrangement:  We have six objects to arrange: ABE, HID, C, F, G, H, I, J.  Since the objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $6!$ ways.

*Arrangements with three prohibited substrings*:  Since BED and HID cannot both appear in an arrangement of the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, there are no arrangements in which ABE, BED, and HID all appear.

Therefore, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of arrangements of the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J in which none of the substrings ABE, BED, and HID appear is 
$$10! - 3 \cdot 8! + 7! + 6!$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

$_{10}P_3$ is not the number of arrangements where $ABE$ occurs.  You have $7!$ ways to put the other letters in order and $8$ places to put the unit $ABE$ so $8!$ ways to put all the letters in order including $ABE$.  Alternately, you can group $ABE$ into one letter, have $8$ letters, which again gives $8!$ orders.

Your double subtraction is combinations with $ABED$ and combinations with both $ABE$ and $HID$, so you need to add those back in once.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a little stuck. Can someone let me know how close my answer actually is??

Comment: It is not close at all.  The first term is correct, but only that one.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ABE$ and $HID$ are disjoint, all Permutations where both patterns occur are subtracted twice.

Comment: So I should subtract $_{10}P_2$ twice?

Comment: @HiddenDragon No you should add back the number of permutations where both patterns occur as you already have subtracted them twice. You have the patterns $\ldots ABE \ldots HID \ldots$ and $\dots HID \ldots ABE \ldots$ You must figure out in how many ways the other letters can be arranged within the $\ldots$ By the way the $ABE$ and $BED$ patterns need to be corrected as well I think. I need a bit to figure that out.

Comment: Please someone with a clear answer clarify this.... please good formatting

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot the spaces after `\ldots`. Anyway as there are 6 slots left for the other letters and the three $\dots$ themselves can each contain $0\ldots6$ with a total of $6$ they can be of the forms $(0,0,6),(0,1,5),(0,2,4)\ldots(6,0,0)$

Comment: I guess your reasoning for the $ABE$ and $BED$ case is sound.

Comment: @diffset:  you did not point out that OP is wrong in counting the combinations for each triplet originally, even before correcting for the double counting.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, actually I didn't know this $_{n}P_m$ notation. Got confused by it.

Comment: It is the number of ways to select $m$ things in order out of $n$.  It equals $\frac {n!}{(n-m)!}$ in analogy to $_nC_r$ for combinations.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, thanks. I thought it meant more than that. Just what you wrote in your answer. Therefore, I only noticed the double count of the disjoint patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the result: Brute force tells me $3513600$.

But let's figure this out. There are $10!$ permutations in total. We have to subtract those with $ABE$. There are $8!$ of them (just treat $ABE$ as a single letter). Likewise, we have $8!$ for each of the other two three letter patterns. That leaves us with $10!-3\cdot8!$. Now we have subtracted patterns like $\ldots{}ABE\ldots{}HID\ldots$ twice. How many of them are there? The number of letters left is $4$ with $4!$ permutations of them and exactly two out of 5 spots (the spots before between and after the four letters) where the two patterns are inserted. Assume the first pattern goes into the first slot. Then the second one can also go there or into the second or third and so on. If the first pattern goes into the second slot the second one can only go into the second or third and so on. This means there are $\sum_{i=1}^{5}i=15$ possibilities. As $ABE$ can be the first or the second pattern, we multiply by $2$ which gives us a total of $4!\cdot15\cdot2=720$ permutations with both $ABE$ and $HID$ in them. Now, $HID$ and $BED$ can obviously never occur simultaneously. But $ABE$ and $BED$ can. How often does that happen. Just treat $ABED$ as one letter then there are $7!$ of them. They also need to be put back in. We end up with $$10!-3\cdot8!+4!\cdot15\cdot2+7!=3513600$$

Comment: I think I almost got it. So far, I have $_{10}P_{10} - (3*8! - x)$, where I don't know what $x$ is. Can you clarify what I should add back in? I am still confused

Comment: I just edited my answer only to see afterwards that there already was a correct answer. :-)